# How to read and parse an XML which exist inside the page using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I have an xml file which I imported in my html page like this:

```
<script type="text/xml" src="Categories.xml" id="categoriesXML">  
</script>
```

And using my jQuery code I want to read this xml file and parse it to do some stuff with its data, so I tried to write something like this:

```
 var xml = $('#categoriesXML').text();
    $(xml).find("Category").each(function () {
        alert($(this).find("Title").text());
    });
```

But what I got is that the xml variable is empty.

I also tried to write it:

```
var xml = $('#categoriesXML');
```

but again I can't get it work.

The xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Categories>
  <Category>
    <Title>CAT1</Title>
    <SubCategories>
      <SubCategory>
        <Title>SUB1</Title>
      </SubCategory>
    </SubCategories>
  </Category>
</Categories>
```

So how to read this xml file this way, **without using ajax**?

**Why I want it without ajax:**
Because I want this to happen on the page load, and no need to start getting the file after my page loads which will show my page nearly empty at first load, and will wait till the ajax response with the file which may be very big in some cases.

Comment: And how do you intend to speed things up? With a magic wand? Your XML is big, OK, the browser can't load the XML before the page, that's a fact. So whatever method you will be using, there WILL be some delay. You are trying to achieve a server-side behaviour on the client side.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but for example I can fix this by adding the content of the xml file as content of a hidden field which get its data using server side code, so that the page will come to the client ready with the xml.

Comment: If you have access to some server-side technology, then use it and forget about javascript. It will be faster and accessible by 100% of your visitors and/or search engine robots.

Comment: In my case I will need in both cases to access the xml using jquery, because jQuery code will do some edits on the page later using these xml data.

Comment: Then use the server-side to display the default view and then load the XML using ajax for further manipulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to load the XML with AJAX.
Here is a [summary](http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/) of the way to do it

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will work that way , you should probably load it document.ready through ajax and start processing it.

Make an ajax call in the document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   // make ajax call and populate xml and process the xml.


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a synchronous AJAX request at the top of the page to populate your JavaScript variable. It will mimic the inline XML.

Comment: Synchronous AJAX? LOL. Please define AJAX ;-)

Comment: @Capsule. From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): "By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false.".

Answer (score 0):

I will write some server side code to render the xml content directly on the page to be as in this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Cq8Fu/ and like that It will work, because using an external file It will not work and as @Capsule said in his comments above, there will be a delay to load the file and this work around is useless and will not save time at all.

By the way this sample I got from an answer someone answered here but he deleted his answer later "don't know why".

Comment: Deleted because `<script type="text/xml">` is invalid and the example was not loading anything remotely, it had the XML source inside the script tag. This *might* work in Internet Explorer according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Btw, this example works in Firefox but not in Safari (and probably not in Chrome).

Comment: Yes it is not working on my mac safari, what will be the solution do you think?

Comment: See my last comment on your question.